# Prove that G is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The exercise is:

> Let $g\in G$. $G$ is a group. Prove that $G=\{gx:x\in G$}.

I know the the definition of group but the proof that is in the book is the next one:

> Let $H=\{gx:x\in G\}$
>
> $H\subseteq G$ because
>
> $g\in G$ and $x\in G$ $\Rightarrow gx \in G$
>
> G $\subseteq H$ (?)
>
> (by definition) Let $x\in G$.
>
> We want $x=gy$
>
> $x=gy/\cdot g^{-1} \Leftrightarrow g^{-1}x=y$
>
> $x=g(g^{-1}x)$
>
> $y\in G$ : $g\in G \Rightarrow g^{-1} \in G$
>
> so, $g^{-1}\in G$ and $x\in G$ $\Rightarrow g^{-1}x \in G \Rightarrow x\in H$

I don't understand what is the idea behind all this. What I see is that we made a subset that is same as superset and proved that they are the same. Can you please explain.

Comment: That's the usual interpretation of equality of sets. $A=B$ means that they have the same elements. That is, each element of $A$ is an element of $B$ and vice versa. In other words, $A\subseteq B$ and $A\supseteq B$. In this exercise, you are proving $G=H$.

Comment: Perhaps you are misunderstanding the question.  It is NOT whether this set is a group (you refer to the definition of a group and title this "prove G is a group" which is given) but whether or not the set is equal to the underlying set of G.

Comment: I understand but why are we proving that the set is same as itself?

Comment: You are not proving that the set is the same as itself.  If we take a particular $g\in G$ and multiply each $x\in G$ to that $g$, will get every element of $G$.

Comment: Oh I'm getting it. So we tell that H is the group that we want to prove G is, so then we prove the equality of sets between G and H. I wasn't understanding the problem. Thank you all very much.

Comment: I find the reasoning is easier to follow if you draw out the table of a small group G (say 4 or 5 elements). For one, every element x must "shift" the elements differently, because otherwise you will have a row/column in G's operation table with a duplicate element, and that wouldn't be the table of a group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is a set-up to [Cayley's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem), which says roughly that *every* group can be thought of as a group of permutations.

You're being asked to show that there's a bijection between the **sets** $G$ and $\{gx : x\in G\}$. You show that the *set* of elements that make up $G$ are exactly the same set of elements that make up $\{gx: x \in G\}$ (in this case, by showing each is a subset of the other).

---

The motivation is that if we pick a group element $g \in G$ and left multiply every group element by $g$, this defines a permutation of the elements of $G$;  you're just jumbling up the group elements. We can formalize this by saying that there's a bijection

\begin{align*}
\ell_g\colon G &\to \{gx: x \in G\} = G \\
x &\mapsto gx,
\end{align*}

since permutations are just bijections between a set and itself. So you pick an element $g \in G$, and it determines a permutation of $G$, sending $x$ to $gx$. We get a permutation for *every* $g \in G$, and we say that $G$ *acts on itself* by left multiplication.

That's *why* you'd be asked to prove something like this; by viewing the result the right way, you've essentially proven Cayley's Theorem.

Comment: I like this answer because you not only answer the question but provide motivation. +1

Comment: the maps $\ell_g$ are very important for other branches of math, including affine geometry, lie groups, and operator theory, so +1 from me, as well.

Answer (score 4):

The idea for the proof is that for $2$ sets $A,B$
$$
A=B\iff A\subset B \land B\subset A
$$
To prove $A\subset B$, use
$$
A\subset B\iff \forall x\in A\implies x\in B
$$
So to prove $G=H$, just prove $G\subset H$ and $H\subset G$.

To prove $G\subset H$, just prove that if $x\in G$ then $x\in H$.