# The role of visualization and intuition in graduate and postgraduate math and developing it

Tags: soft-question, intuition, visualization

In *Visual Complex Analysis*'s preface, the author gives an analogy with pseudo-deaf musicians and follows the same to mathematics. Mathmatics today, he argues, is mostly build on abstract symbolic manipulation rather than much more stronger visual (intuition) method.

Is it a good notion to rely on visualization and intuition solely on graduate and postgraduate mathematics on topics like Analysis, Abstract Algebra and other fields (Topology and differential geometry is pretty obvious - it is probably visual per se) ?

If yes, then how to visualize and develop intuition in graduate and postgraduate mathematics in fields mostly relying on (stupid; ?) symbolic manipulation ?

Comment: This is an interesting but broad question.  It might be better suited to the mathematics educators stack exchange.

Comment: There *can* be a visual side to algebra, but I think that visualization is another form of story-telling, and that story-telling is really a good way to cope with math, including algebra and everything else. Here's an [example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414072/prove-that-g-is-a-group/1414111#1414111) of the sort of thing I mean.

Comment: Just a tangential note: You might be interested in the [remembrance for Bill Thurston](http://www.ams.org/notices/201511/rnoti-p1318.pdf) in the _AMS Notices_.

Comment: Symbolic manipulation appeals to those of us who rely primarily on [stupidity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610016/how-much-of-pure-mathematics-is-first-order-logic#comment3281644_1610016).

Comment: @pjs36: Sounds interesting. What you mean by mathematical story telling ? What are the sub skills (including visualization) related to it ? How to develop this skill ?

Comment: Topology is not necessarily visual; it depends on the topologist. Some people think primarily in visual terms, some primarily in what I might call more algebraic terms, and some occupy various points between the extremes. I’m a topologist who does not use a lot of visualization.

Comment: @Karl:  I have posted it here: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10529/the-role-of-visualization-and-intuition-in-graduate-and-postgraduate-math-and-de . You may answer it here too.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I assume it would be benificial if one is good at both i.e (or e.g ) wrapping one's geometrical (or visual) intuition in algebraic terms. The unpacking of the geometrical intuition from the algebraic wrapper is lacking, and that's why I am asking how to do that/

Answer (score 1):

The best way to develop intuition is to practice, as far as I know. At that level, it's best to read some research papers and implement them on your own. After 30-40 times, you will yourself understand that you got some intuition into things.